# Is it possible to create an custom response in laravel on methodNotAllowed

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-8, http-status-code-405

I've been searching a solution in Google but couldn't find anything similar tho this. 
I'm basically trying to create a custom response upon the error **methodNotAllowed** in the framework **Laravel 8.x**
So I have this route:

```php
Route::get('/test', function(Request $request){
    return response([
        'status' => 200,
        'data' => 'Test'
    ]);
});
```

On requesting `GET:/api/test` I'm getting the expected response:

```json
{
    "status":   200,
    "data":     "Test"
}
```

But when requesting `POST:/api/test` or any other method it obviously throws an error `405 Method Not Allowed` because I haven't setup any router for this.

Is there a "cleen way" to change the error response from `405 Method Not Allowed` to

```json
{
    "status":   405,
    "data":     "Method Not Allowed"
}
```

By a "cleen way" I mean not creating aditional 100 routes just for catching the right method.

Comment: [Rendering exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions)

Comment: Thx, I think  thats the right one

Answer (score 3):

The Solution was adding the custom Response to `App\Exceptions\Handler` by doing this:
Add this to the top:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
```

And add the custom response to the method `register`:

```php
public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (MethodNotAllowedHttpException $e, $request) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 405,
                'message' => 'Method Not Allowed'
            ], 405);
        });
    }
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors